# Flutter app bundle - not compatible with emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-bundle

I've recently released a Flutter app into Play store and wanted to test its functionality via specific emulator - tried to install from the store and turns out that it is not compatible (x86 not included in app bundle?)

I never had such problems with my Java app bundles - they just work out of the box.
This time I used Flutter deploying via app bundle...

So how can I fix this to include x86 into app bundle that Flutter generates? I'm using Android Studio for this process btw.

Also found this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33424 seems like I'm not the only one with such problem, but it dates back to 2019.. still not fixed?

Comment: That issue seems to be for arm 64 bits. There's an active one for x86 in release mode that I haven't followed for years. Last time I checked yep, no release builds for x86, only Debug.